# Embed Youtube video and apply file sharing system in SVG-EDIT

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, svg-edit

Is it possible to insert video to svg file ([svg-edit editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.4/editor/svg-editor.html))  ? I would like to use svg-edit for team-work and video youtube insertion is missing at the moment. I found some examples but they does not work, for example [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066648/youtube-iframe-embedded-in-svg-moves-to-front-whilst-playing-in-chrome). Can you please refer me to some resources, which way embed youtube video into svg file in svg-edit  ?

Answer (score 0):

you can embed html content using  element like:

```
<foreignObject width="100" height="50"
               requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
    </body>
</foreignObject>
```

you need to specify width and height and include  tag with xmlns namespace declaration    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

and here's working example (there are some issues with positionning in chrome so best viewed in firefox):

See the Pen NES superAnotherWorld by @rafszul (@rafszul) on CodePen.